# LibGDX - how do I use dynamic position for actors?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

i am building a board game but I have some problems about position of actors. Position of the actor is different on desktop and android.
I solve the problem of size of actor using

```
float height= Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.088f;
float width= Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * 0.088f;
```

StampAdapter class generate stamps automatically. I add position of the stamp manually so this cause some problem on different screen sizes such as desktop and mobile.

```
//StampActor("name",texture, position x,position y,width,height);
stamps.add(new StampActor("Player_Stamp_1",texturePlayer,536.19995F,423.6F  ,width,height));
        stamps.add(new StampActor("Player_Stamp_2",texturePlayer,536.19995F,384.6F  ,width,height));
        stamps.add(new StampActor("Player_Stamp_3",texturePlayer,60.19999F,423.6F  ,width,height));
        stamps.add(new StampActor("Player_Stamp_4",texturePlayer,60.19999F,384.6F  ,width,height));
```

Game screen class add the actor to stage.

```
    for(StampActor stamp : stamps.getStamps()) {
        new MoveStamps(Game,stamp ,locX,locY);
        Game.stage.addActor(stamp);
 }
```

On Android :[Screenshot of Android Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syfe3.png)

On Desktop : [Screenshot Desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNNL3.jpg)

Comment: Which Viewport are you using? Don't use ScreenViewport.

Comment: Would be my recommendation, too: Don't mess around with actor positions but fix it with a viewport.